# *ngIf condition is met with true but template not reloading

Tags: typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-material, angular7, angular-template

I have encountered a weird problem while working with angular 7 *ngIf condition is met my template is not reloading.
this is parent component template and `app-test-step-tree-alt-view-d3` and `app-test-stpe-tree-view-d3` are child component

```
<div *ngIf="showD3view || showD3Altview">
  <app-test-step-tree-alt-view-d3 *ngIf="showD3Altview" (elementsEmit)="onChildboxSelection($event)" [altPathFlagD3]="altPathFlagD3" [altPathFlagTable]="altPathFlagTable"></app-test-step-tree-alt-view-d3>
  <app-test-stpe-tree-view-d3 *ngIf="showD3view" (elementsEmit)="onChildboxSelection($event)" [altPathFlagD3]="altPathFlagD3" [altPathFlagTable]="altPathFlagTable"></app-test-stpe-tree-view-d3>
  <div class="pavv">
    <div class="backcolor">

        <section class="alternatePathPosition altPath-section">
          <mat-slide-toggle
              class="altPath-margin"
              [color]="color"
              [checked]="altPathFlagD3" 
  (change)="toggleD3($event)">
            Alternate Path
          </mat-slide-toggle>
        </section>
      <img
      id="listViewImg"
        src="./assets/images/listView.png"
        class="viewTreePosition"
        (click)="setListFlags()"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and Typescript code

```
  toggleD3(event){
   this.showD3Altview=event.checked;
   this.altPathFlagTable=String(event.checked);
   this.altPathFlagD3=String(event.checked);
   debugger;
   if(this.showTreeview){
    if(this.showD3Altview && this.showD3view){
      this.showD3Altview=true;
      this.showD3view=false;
   }else{
    //this block executes but doesn't reloads template
    this.showD3Altview=false;
    this.showD3view=true;
   }
   }
  }
```

flag is getting set as usual in console but when user plays around template does not reloads.
Please help me on that I am new to angular

Comment: Please be more explicit. What precisely are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Note that both views are shown is showD3Altview. It's probably not what you want.

Comment: Yes thanks that was a typo i will correct it asap 

Comment: @JBNizet it is just a toggle for show and hide only just setting flag only it is just d3 tree with two types of tree when toggle done quickly